# How does quantum electrodynamics apply to a uniform charge distribution in all space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrostatics, quantum-electrodynamics

In Gauss's law for electricity it is required to consider a closed surface, which $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not. Therefore if a uniform charge distribution $\rho$ occupies all of space, the classical theory for electromagnetism can't be applied to obtain the electric field. Intuitively, this electric field must have a value of zero.

I understand that quantum electrodynamics is a more complete theory to describe electromagnetism, therefore I thought that it might be possible to prove with it that the electric field is zero for a uniform charge distribution through all of space. From what I understand, in quantum mechanics charge is in a continuum rather than being discrete. Therefore it is more fitting for the uniform charge distribution. The question therefore is: Is the electric field produced by $\rho$ zero in all $\mathbb{R}^n$ using quantum electrodynamics ?

P.S. My motivation for this question is that there is also an issue in newtonian gravity by using a uniform distribution of mass through all of space, and can only be understood by using GR. I thought that it would be very elegant if the same issue occured in electromagnetism where quantum mechanics must be involved, since GR and quantum mechanics are famously complicated to join.

Comment: Related: [Gauss's law in a uniform charge distribution extending infinitely in all directions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194136), and [Why isn't an infinite, flat, nonexpanding universe filled with a uniform matter distribution a solution to Einstein's equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/430419).